# How can I write one line code instead of taking mean of each variable inside the group_by()?

Tags: r, group-by, na

My code is following:

```
mtmm_data4 <- mtmm_data  %>% group_by(cntry_lan, admdw) %>% 
  summarise( M1T1 = mean(M1T1, na.rm = TRUE), M1T2 = mean(M1T2, na.rm = TRUE), M1T3 = mean(M1T3, na.rm= TRUE), M2T1 = mean(M2T1, na.rm= TRUE), M2T2 = mean(M2T2, na.rm=TRUE), M2T3 = mean(M2T3, na.rm=TRUE), M3T1 = mean(M3T1, na.rm), M3T2 = mean(M3T2, na.rm=TRUE), M3T3 = mean(M3T3, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Also this code created a data set where all M2T1, M3T1, M3T2 are NANs. I did not understand why I would have had such NAs.

Comment: summarise(across(c(YOUR_COLUMNS), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: @JonSpring, I just posted, refreshed, and saw your comment ... post your answer please :-)

Comment: Why would I have this warning "Warning: argument is not numeric or logical:" ? 20 or more lines I am having warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mtmm_data  %>% 
   group_by(cntry_lan, admdw) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(YOUR_COLUMNS), ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Have a look at the [tidyselect](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) functions for some helpers that might make it simpler / more flexible to select the columns you want to summarize.

EDIT --

It sounds like your data might have been read in as `character` instead of numeric, which would error out when you take the `mean`. Examine your data types (e.g. `str(mtmm_data)` or `glimpse(mtmm_data)`) and if that's the case, the best thing would be to fix it upstream when you load the data. You could also do it here with something like:

```
mtmm_data  %>% 
   group_by(cntry_lan, admdw) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(YOUR_COLUMNS), ~mean(as.numeric(.), na.rm = TRUE)))
```